# Varnish custom html based on User Agent

Tags: varnish

I want to display different html styles to users based on `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']`. How can I achieve this with varnish settings, to make it have a specific cache for a specific user agent.

I know I can achieve something similar with JS, but that's not reliable for me I want to do it server side.

The php I will use in my html to detect user agents will look like this;

```
<?php if($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] == $target):?>
    <style>
      //CSS
    </style>    
    <?php endif;?>
```

How can I setup **Varnish** so it work neatly with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is modify the `vcl_hash` method to add more info to the cache key.

https://varnish-cache.org/docs/trunk/users-guide/vcl-hashing.html

```
sub vcl_hash {
    hash_data(req.http.User-Agent);
}
```

Be aware that there are no real standards that are followed for User Agent strings, so the variations are huge even for what are identical browsers. I would expect a 99% cache miss on this technique unless you will be controlling the User Agents yourself (internal system etc.)

If you want a different cache for mobile devices, the following might be more successful as it tries to detect a mobile browser, then uses a normalised cache key value to improve hit rate:

```
sub vcl_hash {
  if (req.http.User-Agent ~ "mobile") {
    // hash_data
    hash_data("mobile");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Varnish supports that by default. You don't need to change Varnish's configuration. You only need to send the [Vary header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Vary):

> The Vary HTTP response header determines how to match future request headers to decide whether a cached response can be used rather than requesting a fresh one from the origin server.

In your specific case where you want it to vary based on the User-Agent, Varnish will understand that it needs to create different versions of the same object in cache for each different User-Agent.

Beware that using varying you cache might reduce your hit-rate considerably due to the number of variations the User-Agent header has. To avoid that, normalization is required. You can read more normalizing User-Agent headers in [Varnish's documentation](https://varnish-cache.org/docs/trunk/users-guide/devicedetection.html)

Comment: it's one specific user agent I want to target, am using hash_data now on my V3 and it's working what's the diffrent between Hash and Vary, do I need to drop hash and use Vary? why?

Comment: No need @Kash. Just another bit of information and an additional way of accomplishing the same thing.